# How do you get from one step to another in implicit differentiation?

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

So trying to understand the step process here,

$$y^2 - 2x = 1 - 2y$$

So after a few simplifications we get:

$$yy' - 1 = -y'$$

But what I am confused on is how that turns into

$$(y+1)y' = 1$$

I know the answer and understand it, but I don't understand how the $-1$ (left side) and $-y'$ (right side) become positive.

Comment: There is no need for the odd apostrophe; you can typeset the "prime" symbol by actually just using a right apostrophe as follows: $2y'$ is produced by writing `$2y'$`. Alternatively, you can typeset the same thing by writing `$2y^\prime$`, but the other construction is much easier and saves time. For more information about typesetting, see [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
y^2-2x &= 1-2y\\[0.5em] 
{} &\Downarrow {}\\[0.5em]
2yy'-2 &= -2y'\\[0.5em]
{} &\Downarrow {}\\[0.5em]
yy' - 1 &= -y'\\[0.5em]
{} &\Downarrow {}\\[0.5em]
yy'+y' &= 1\\[0.5em]
{} &\Downarrow {}\\[0.5em]
y'(y+1) &= 1\\[0.5em]
{} &\Downarrow {}\\[0.5em]
y' &= \frac{1}{y+1}
\end{align}

Comment: ah ok. i get it now.

Answer (score 3):

Think of $y'$ as a variable, say, $Z$
$$yZ - 1 = -Z$$

Adding $Z+1$ to both side yields $yZ+Z = 1$ which becomes $Z(y+1) = 1$, or $$(y+1)y'=1$$